# Place a label in the middle of the screen for all devices Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have got a label and now my soul desires to put that label in the middle of the screen.
I have tried putting vertical and horizontal constraints but it didn't make any difference.I don't have anything on my app except image that covers the whole background and this label

Comment: This is hard to answer. Do you mean you want to center the label on the *window*? Or the window on the screen? Is this about OSX or iOS?

Comment: @fbitterlich label on the _window_,it's for IOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click-drag from the label onto its container (the background) and select "Center vertically in Container". Repeat for "Center horizontally in Container". That should do it.